# Unsaved changes in Umbraco 7.6

Tags: umbraco7

I am experiencing a weird problem with one of my document types.

When I save, publish, and go to another node - the following notification appears: "You have unsaved changes".

My document type consists of:

```
RTE Tags Media picker Textbox Multinode Treepicker True False
```

I cant find the declaration dirty on any of them.

Help anyone?

Comment: Have you waited for save action to complete all the way with the message - "Content published: and visible online"?